# Angular Resource - intercepting and transforming request/response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to transform / intercept some requests in my angular + closure project *but not all requests* to change my camelCase keys to snake_case.

I managed to add a default interceptors and transformers with `$httpProvider` in my config however this did all requests including templates. Adding an option in each of my Resource configs i could allow / disallow the transforms however that config option is only accessible in requests not responses meaning I'd have to check if its JSON first which isn't ideal.

I believe also transforms get the raw request body (or maybe it was interceptors I can't remember with all the testing i did) and converting it to and from JSON etc seems error prone.

The interceptor for `$resource` only allows `response` and `responseError` interceptors for some frustrating reason.

Is there any way to intercept each request/response JSON object where I can keep the transformers in its own file / class / factory and either allow it or require the function and call it on each request?

What would the best route be to take for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `$http` interceptor. `$resource` is using `$http` service in the background to make requests, so it will be applied.

```
function MyInterceptor() {
    return {
        request: config => {
            // do your logic here
            // you can modify only end-points you want to modify by using if statements
        }
    }
}

function config($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyInterceptor');
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('MyInterceptor', MyInterceptor)
    .config(config);
```